# jQUery - insert &nbsp; inside label

Tags: jquery

I want to hide a label using the `fadeOut` effect but when it is completed I want to insert inside it a `&nbsp;`

```
 $('label.alert').fadeOut('slow',function(){$(this).text('&nbsp;');});
```

but it produces a `&nbsp;` as a raw text. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Use `.html()` instead of `.text()`.

Comment: I would think that .html might add some extra overhead compared to .text

Comment: @dsdsdsdsd - When you start thinking like that you stray dangerously close to performing premature optimization: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization - if .text isn't working, you shouldn't use it whether it causes overhead or not (although honestly, I would think .text would have more overhead since it has to escape your string, then unescape it. IDK, I don't do much web programming.)

Answer (score 5):

Be careful with using `.html()` or the same methods using another framework/library (e.g `v-html` in Vue.js), because it has XSS vulnerability. Read more about XSS from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15928704/2160038).

**Working way via .text():**
You can simply replace `&nbsp;` with `\xa0` for text messages.

Answer (score 0):

`replaceWith` did the trick

```
$('label.alert').fadeOut('slow',function(){$(this).replaceWith('<label class="alert">&nbsp;</label>');});
```