# javascript XSS sanitizing if data is already sanitized using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

**Update:**

### I'm still confused as ever. Can someone please reply to my last comment?

If all my data (+title1+ and +title2+ in this example -- see below) is sanitized using PHP do I need to worry about javascript as well? I'm concerned about my use of title='"+title2+"' (the apostrophes is my concern) in my code below.

**html\javascript:**

```
 <div id="verification"></div>

 <script>


function update() {
    $.ajax({
    url: 'update.php', //php          
    data: "", 
    dataType: 'json',   
    success: function (data) {
        //on receive of reply
        var title1 = data[0];
        var title2 = data[1];          

        $('#verification').html("<img src=images/test"+title1+".gif title='"+title2+"'></img>");     //output to html
        }
    });
}

</script>
```

***json response***

```
["1","test test test"]
```

***output (by Mouseover text with Title)***

```
test test test
```

***php*** (php sanitizing omitted)

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT title1, title2 FROM users WHERE username = '$foobar'")
or die(mysql_error());
$array = mysql_fetch_row($result);
echo json_encode($array);
```

Comment: Need to explain your issue in more detail. Really not clear what you are asking or what problems you are having

Comment: I asked if I sanitized the data +title1+ +title2+ previously with PHP if my use of title='"+title2+"' (the apostrophes is my concern) is safe

Comment: You should worry more about using deprecated PHP functions `mysql_*`.

Comment: Right. I should be using PDO, but what about my question.

Comment: Could this help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318581/html-vs-innerhtml-jquery-javascript-xss-attacks

Comment: So what I learned from that link is there are two types of XSS attacks...  self-XSS and DOM based. The rest is jargon to me.

Comment: So if the data is sanitized via PHP... can         $('#verification').html("<img src=images/test"+title1+".gif title='"+title2+"'></img>");     //output to html
 be exploited in any way or is it structurally sound?

Comment: I wish there was some sort of bump button on this site. I'm still confused as ever. I'm just going to assume since I used preg_replace a-zA-Z0-9 (PHP) for the data saved to my mysql db for title1 and title2 that $('#verification').html("<img src=images/test"+title1+".gif title='"+title2+"'></img>"); is safe against XSS javascript exploits I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different elements that need to be considered:

- database: use prepared statements (PDO or mysqli) to avoid SQL injection via user input
- UI: escape user input as required to avoid [XSS attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)

While the user input has been '*santizied*' for queries against the database through the PDO/mysqli prepared statements, further consideration is required before presenting the user input back on the web page in the browser.

Comment: ... and there are even [2nd Level SQL injection](http://stackoverflow.com/a/134138/457723) attack vectors.